# How to make mysql difference between between uppercase and lowercase

Tags: mysql, utf-8, uppercase, alter-table, lowercase

I need something in mysql for difference between between uppercase and lowercase in a query.

Because I need it in my java program for select the user name.

I tried this:

- database name utf8
- table name is `user_table`

Query:

```
create table user_table (id int, name varchar(30));

insert into a user_table (1, "zdi0"), (2, "ZDI0");

ALTER DATABASE utf8 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE user_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

select * 
from a 
where name = "ZDI0" ;
```

Result:

```
1  zdi0
2  ZDI0
```

I need to alter the table not the query

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanx @R Mac but this is work for one table in database but i have more than one table in database and i have error say : Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of '.\pind_try\#sql-85c_aa' to '.\pind_try\profile' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 3):

The collation scheme utf8_unicode_ci is case insensitive. If you want to use utf8 collation and support case sensitivity, you'll need to use utf8_bin, but utf8_bin is a binary collation scheme. You should read up on it before you decide to use it. Unfortunately as far as I know utf8_bin is the only case sensitive utf8 collation currently available in MySQL.

Comment: this is work for one table in database but i have more than one table in database and i have error say : Error Code: 1025. Error on rename of '.\pind_try\#sql-85c_aa' to '.\pind_try\profile' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare values for exact case, you can use `'binary'` function.

**Example**:

```
mysql> select ( @U := 'Ravinder' ) = ( @L := 'ravinder' ) as `true`
    ->      , @U=binary( @L ) as `false`;
+------+-------+
| true | false |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

This usage makes an explicit comparison for exact match, no matter what the collation is.